# Olympiad number theory question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

**Question** -

Some sets of prime numbers, such as $\{7,83,421,659\},$ use each of the nine nonzero digits exactly once. What is the smallest possible sum such a set of primes can have?

**Solution**: The answer is $207$. Note that digits $4,6$ and $8$ cannot appear in the units digit. Hence the sum is at least $40+60+80+1+2+3+5+7+9=207.$

***how they found that this is the least sum ???***

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  It's clear from what you have written that there can not be an example with a smaller sum, so all that remains is to try to find an example with this sum, though that does not look difficult.

Comment: Because least prime containing $4,6,8$ in the $2$nd place are $47, 61, 83$. So we have included $1,3,4,6,7,8$. Primes made of $2,5,9$ with least sum is are themselves. But $9$ isn't a prime. So, we can just interchange $3$ and $9$.

Comment: "What is the smallest possible sum such a set can have" - with exactly $4$ primes, or also with more? In your example $(7,83,421,659)$ we have exactly $4$ primes.

Comment: @DietrichBurde As many primes as you like - obviously not more than $9$ nor fewer then $1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They basically constructed the set with the minimum sum, which is
$$
A = \{1,2,3,5,7,9\}
$$
but it is missing $4,6,8$ since the numbers ending on them cannot be prime, so they have to add it into tens instead of units digits. Since 9 is not prime you add one of them to 9 to make sure you get a prime (and the only one that works is an $8$ since $49=7 \cdot 7$ and $69 = 3 \cdot 13$), ending up with, for example,
$$
\{41,2,3,5,67,89\}
$$
Whichever way $4,6,8$ are added,they will contribute to the total sum $40+60+80$, and hence, the total sum is $40+60+80$ and the sum of elements in $A$...

Comment: 9 is not a prime.

Comment: $9$ isn't a prime. So, interchange $3$ and $9$. The ultimate set will be $47,61,89,2,3,5$.

Comment: 40,60,80 is also not a prime..

Comment: @AlapanDas - I think  that is not the only example

Comment: i did not understand reason behind adding 40,60,80 to the sum

Comment: Because $47=40+7$ ;$61=60+1$ and $89=80+9$.

Comment: @Sil updated the answer to correct for the $9$ and others

Comment: @Ishan $40,60,80$ are not numbers in the set, but they give the contribution for $4,6,8$

Comment: @gt6989b "$4,6,8$ since the numbers ending on them cannot be prime, so they have to add it into tens instead of units digit" sorry,but this does not make any sense to me at all...can you pls give more details

Comment: @Ishan numbers ending on $4,6,8$ are even and cannot be prime. $2$ is the only even number which is prime.

Answer (score 1):

They found a lower bound and then looked for an example.

In such an example,

- the $2$ and $5$ would be single digit numbers,
- the $1$ cannot be a single digit number; nor can it be in $81$ so must be in $41$ or $61$
- the $9$ cannot be a single digit number; nor can it be in $49$ or $69$ so must be in $89$
- $41$ and $43$ and $47$ are prime
- $61$ and $67$ are prime

So the possibilities are

$$2,3,5,41,67,89$$
$$2,3,5,47,61,89$$
$$2,5,7,43,61,89$$

Comment: ok, but i am asking how they found the least sum ???

Comment: $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9=45$ is the smallest sum of the digits and thus a lower bound, but $4,6,8$ cannot be the final digit of prime numbers, so another lower bound is $1+2+3+40+5+60+7+80+9=207$.  If you can find an example with $207$ as the sum of primes (I found three) then this is the smallest possible, since it is equal to the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

The remaining task is to find a representation of $207$. 
This is easy, for example,
$$
207=2+3+5+41+67+89.
$$
More interesting would be the question what the minimum of *four* such
primes is, such as suggested already in the text, with $
7,83,421,659$ (which have sum $1170$). Then the minimum is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

A combination with *all ten* digits and what could be a minimal sum is $2,5,83,109,467$ with a devilish ([or not](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/616_(number))) sum of $666$.